# When I go back to a view controller after opening it previously it does not animate labels Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

When I open my app I have this label that animates in from outside the screen. When I open the view controller for the first time it works. However, when I go to another view controller and then go back to the initial view controller this label will just be there and not animate in.

```
    levelsLabel.center = CGPoint(x:levelsLabel.center.x - 500, y:levelsLabel.center.y)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {

        self.levelsLabel.center = CGPoint(x:self.levelsLabel.center.x + 500, y:self.levelsLabel.center.y)

    }
```

Anyone have any suggestions?? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting your block of code in `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad` will make it work. However, according to [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html).

> `viewDidAppear`: Use this method to trigger any operations that need
>   to occur as soon as the view is presented onscreen, such as fetching
>   data or showing an animation.

The following is what I'd recommend you to do.

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        levelsLabel.center = CGPoint(x:levelsLabel.center.x - 500, y:levelsLabel.center.y)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
            self.levelsLabel.center = CGPoint(x:self.levelsLabel.center.x + 500, y:self.levelsLabel.center.y)

        }
    }
```

Comment: will this affect anything else

Comment: I'm not sure what is "anything else". You may want to take a look at this View Controller lifecycle: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html to figure it out.

Comment: @Lawliet, agreed with ur answer. but how can I achieve this in my UICollectionViewCell class because there is only one method is there override init(frame: CGRect) just like viewDidLoad. Is there any alternate method as viewDidAppear for UICollectionViewCell class programmatically...